# Javascript splice function not working when combining array elements together

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm writing a calculator app. Buttons in html add elements to an array. When the user hits =, it will iterate through the array and combine numbers that have no mathematical symbol between them. However, I have to remove an element each time 2 numbers are combined.

```js
let equation = [1,2,3,"/",1,2,3];
combineNumbers();

function combineNumbers()//call to start finding solution by merging numbers
{
for(let i = 1; i < equation.length;i++)//iterates length of equation starting at 1
{
    if(isFinite(equation[i-1]) && isFinite(equation[i]))//checks if equation[i] and the index before it are numbers
    {
        equation[i-1] = '' + equation[i-1] + equation[i];//combines equation[i] and the index before
        equation.splice[i];//removes element at index i
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }

}
console.log(equation);
}
```

I have tried iterating the length of the array backwards which broke it more.
I've tried different versions of splice including

```
equation.splice[i]
equation.splice[i,1]
```

Current output with equation.splice[i] is [12,23,3,"/",12,23,3]. It should be [123,"/",123]

Comment: Are you trying to *call* `splice`?  If so, use `(...)` instead of `[...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `[ ]` (index/property access) and `( )` (function call). It should be `equation.splice(i, 1)`.

Also, please note that removing an item will shift the other indices, so you will then skip one item unless you manually decrement your counter with `i--` or iterate backwards instead of forwards.

<sub>Also, I'm not sure why you manually skip the next item in your `else`, is that intentional? Perhaps there should not be any `else`?</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what happens when I have to teach 3 of my team mates how to use github and git because they didn't pay attention. Simple mistake that i overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Splicing the array and modifying the length of it while iterating over it at the same time can cause all sorts of different issues. I tried a different approach where I form numbers iteratively and push them to the result array once formed.

```js
let equation = [1,2,"*",3,"/",1,2,3,"+",4];
combineNumbers();

function combineNumbers()//call to start finding solution by merging numbers
{
    let result = [];
  var currentNumberStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < equation.length; i++) {
    let symbol = equation[i];
    if (isFinite(symbol)) {
        currentNumberStr += symbol; // if symbol is a number, append to current number string
    } else {
        // Otherwise, we hit an operator. Push the current number str e.g. "123" and the operator to the result array
      result.push(currentNumberStr);
      result.push(symbol);
      // Reset the current number string
      currentNumberStr = "";
    }
  }
  // At the end, you have a currentNumberStr left over (the end 123). Push that
  result.push(currentNumberStr);
  
  console.log(result);
  
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.splice(index, deleteCount, ...items)` to replace the items in array:
(and use `i--` to repeat loop on the same index)
(and use unary + to convert to number if you convert to string by adding a string, I guess)

```js
let equation = [1, 2, 3, "/", 1, 2, 3];
combineNumbers();

function combineNumbers() //call to start finding solution by merging numbers
{
  for (let i = 1; i < equation.length; i++) //iterates length of equation starting at 1
  {
    if (isFinite(equation[i - 1]) && isFinite(equation[i])) //checks if equation[i] and the index before it are numbers
    {
      let text = '' + equation[i - 1] + equation[i]; //combines equation[i] and the index before 
      equation.splice( /*start*/ i - 1, /*deleteCount*/ 2, /*...items*/ +text); //replace them with a number
      i--; // repeat same i
    }

  }
  console.log(equation);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. If found multiple problems.

1. The check for checking if the equation is a number is wrong.
2. equation.splice needs to have these `( )` instead of these `[ ]` because it's a function
3. `i++;` in the else block is not needed

```js
function combineNumbers()//call to start finding solution by merging numbers
{
    // Save output to local var
    let output = 0;

    //iterates length of equation
    for(let i = 0; i < equation.length;i++)
    {
        //checks if equation[i] is a number
        if(typeof equation[i] === 'number')
        {
            // Adds value to total values var
            ouput += equation[i];
        } else {
            // If equation is not a number do your other stuff here
        }

    }
    // Reset the equation var
    equation = [];
    
    // Log the output
    console.log(ouput);
    return ouput;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).